# Set custom controller properties in the route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I need to define a few properties on the `controller` and till now I'm using the `setupController` method in the relevant route (need to fetch more related data). Today, I realized that all the properties that I'm setting up in this method are actually being attached to the model hash of the controller and not the controller itself.

I need a way to define some properties on the controller after receiving the model and setting it on the controller. The `init` method of the controller doesn't seem to do the job as the model is not set by that time.

In the below example, If you click the log model, you'll see firstname, lastname and email properties. I want the email to be set on the controller and not the model.

[Link to JSBIN](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lolujumaxi/1/edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you're doing is fine, but you need to define the `email` property on the controller:

```
email: null
```

Currently, since Ember sees no `email` property on the controller, it's passing it through and setting it on the model.

Comment: That's it. Haha, I feel dumb. Thanks for the answer.